# How can I make gnuplot skip every other label on the x-axis?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to plot some data using gnuplot. I gather the data on a daily basis, and I want to display the date on the x-axis when that data point was collected. I have figured out how to do that, but as I add data, the date labels begin to overwrite themselves. You can see the effect if you run the following script.

```
# Demonstrates the xtic overlap problem
# set terminal pngcairo size 640, 480
set title "Xtic Overlap Demonstration"
# set output "XticProblem.png"
set yrange[0:]
set xtics rotate font "Times,28"
# set xtics rotate font "Times,10"
set bmargin 7
set tmargin 4
plot "dates_basic.dat" using 2:xtic(1) with linespoints
```

Here is the dataset that I am using to test, stored in file "dates_basic.dat"

```
2023-11-06  0.8
2023-11-07  0.5
2023-11-08  2.0
2023-11-09  0.9
2023-11-10  1.3
2023-11-11  0.7
2023-11-12  1.2
2023-11-13  1.4
2023-11-14  1.5
2023-11-15  1.3
2023-11-16  0.3
2023-11-17  0.4
2023-11-18  0.7
2023-11-19  0.9
2023-11-20  0.4
2023-11-21  0.9
2023-11-22  0.4
2023-11-23  1.3
2023-11-24  1.4
2023-11-25  2.3
2023-11-26  1.8
2023-11-27  1.7
2023-11-28  0.6
2023-11-29  1.2
2023-11-30  1.2
2023-12-01  1.0
2023-12-02  1.7
2023-12-03  1.2
2023-12-04  1.4
2023-12-05  1.0
2023-12-06  1.4
2023-12-07  1.0
2023-12-08  0.4
2023-12-09  1.1
2023-12-10  0.7
```

In the example code I have set a large font so that you can see the effect. I would not normally use that large font, but even if I use a smaller font, the labels will eventually overwrite themselves when I go past a certain number of data points.

I have been trying to fix the issue by skipping every second label, leaving just the tic marks in those locations.

Everything I have tried has failed. I even tried using some modulo arithmetic on the record number to display spaces instead of the label on every other tic.

```
plot "dates_basic.dat" using 2:xtic( $0 % 2 > 0 ? " " : $1 ) with linespoints
```

but that fails with an error saying that $0 is not an integer.

```
"xtics-example.txt" line 10: non-integer operand for %
```

I have been searching for the solution for days, and I have found nothing that works.

How do it skip every other xtic label, or alternatively is there a better way to display the date information?

Thanks,

Banjo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have time data, I wouldn't recommend to use `xtic()` for creating the xtic labels. gnuplot is treating time data as seconds from January, 1st 1970.
And gnuplot has some auto tic implemented (which mostly) gives reasonable results. In your case, it suggests a 7 day interval of the xtic labels, but you can force any other interval in seconds, e.g. 4 days: `set xtics 3600*24*4`.

For further reading, check `help xtics`, `help xtics time`, `help timecolumn`, `help time_specifiers`, etc.

**Data:** `SO77648067.dat`

```
2023-11-06  0.8
2023-11-07  0.5
2023-11-08  2.0
2023-11-09  0.9
2023-11-10  1.3
2023-11-11  0.7
2023-11-12  1.2
2023-11-13  1.4
2023-11-14  1.5
2023-11-15  1.3
2023-11-16  0.3
2023-11-17  0.4
2023-11-18  0.7
2023-11-19  0.9
2023-11-20  0.4
2023-11-21  0.9
2023-11-22  0.4
2023-11-23  1.3
2023-11-24  1.4
2023-11-25  2.3
2023-11-26  1.8
2023-11-27  1.7
2023-11-28  0.6
2023-11-29  1.2
2023-11-30  1.2
2023-12-01  1.0
2023-12-02  1.7
2023-12-03  1.2
2023-12-04  1.4
2023-12-05  1.0
2023-12-06  1.4
2023-12-07  1.0
2023-12-08  0.4
2023-12-09  1.1
2023-12-10  0.7
```

**Script:**

```
### plot time data
reset session

FILE = "SO77648067.dat"

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%Y\n%m-%d" timedate   # \n is newline
# set xtics 3600*24*4               # uncomment this line to force xtic labels every 4 days

plot FILE u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The timecolumn fix works great. I will probably use that technique from now on.

But I thought I would add an answer to my own question anyway since I finally figured out how to do the skip. This may be useful for others who have lots of labels that aren't times and want to skip some of them.

I found out that I can coerce $0 to an integer, and then the modulo arithmetic works.

```
plot "dates_basic.dat" using 2:xtic(int($0)%3 == 0 ? stringcolumn(1) : '') with linespoints
```

In this case, I have made the label print every third tic by using %3 modulo.

The formula came from a very old stackoverflow answer from almost 7 years ago.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346824/gnuplot-skipping-timedat-tics-histogram][1]

I would post an image of the output, but I don't know how to do that on this forum.

Comment: Well, I would use this construct only for very special cases, not for simple time data. You could make this even a little bit shorter: `xtic(int(0)%3 ? '' : strcol(1))`